# Understanding of CreationPolicy

Tags: c#, wpf

Imagine I have 2 XAML pages and a userControl: ***PageA**, **PageB**, **UscGeneral***
***PageA*** will bind to ***ViewModelA*** and ***ViewModelB*** 
***PageB*** will bind to ***ViewModelB***
***UscGeneral*** will bind to ***ViewModelB***

Now, I'll have this ***UscGeneral*** to attached to both **PageA** and **PageB**
***UscGeneral*** will have a ***VisibleFlag*** property to handle visibility of it in pages and ***VisibleFlag*** is in ***ViewModelB***

Now based on certain logic, I'll set the ***VisibleFlag = Visibility.Visible*** and ***UscGeneral*** will appear at the page.

Now my problem comes because ***UscGeneral*** will appear at both page, so when ***VisibleFlag = Visibility.Visible***, this control will appear at both pages which totally makes sense. But my objective is trying to show this control only at ***PageB*** but not ***PageA***.

I've heard that `[Import(RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.NonShared)]` will helps and so I've place it at ***PageB***'s codeBehind. But what happened was, the control is not showing at both ***PageA*** and ***PageB***

May I know how to configure it to achieve what I want?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You want your usercontrol to be never visible on PageA? Then you should not have a ContentControl for it. Perhaps you can show some of your XAML?

Comment: I'll implement logic at ViewModelB and based on the logic to determine if the control should appear at PageA or PageB

Comment: Try setting a bool, like AppearsOnPageA. Then you can easily control visibility with a BooleanToVisibilityConverter (already available in the framework), for PageB you just need the opposite of the converter or a second bool (AppearsOnPageB). Not very smart, but easy to implement and does what you want.